# Bootstrap node that does not rebroadcast transactions?

Tags: private-blockchain, bootnodes, bootstrap

I have a local ethereum network where peers connect to each other based on certain conditions. Local forks and merging occur, so it is common that there are multiple blockchain versions with different lengths.

I want a node that can oversee the network -- that is, be connected to all peers and check the complete mempool, but without rebroadcasting the transactions. Basically -- an audit only node. Is this possible ?